# ¿Como mantener valores de un array php en una tabla HTML?

Tags: php, html

Cordial saludo comunidad.
Les explico mi problema. Tengo una tabla HTML donde se gestionan asientos de un teatro p. ej. y un pequeño formulario donde se introduce la fila y el puesto en dos  cajas de texto y si va a comprar, reservar o liberar un puesto con un radio button, y un boton enviar que de acuerdo a la fila y puesto digitados hace cualquera de las opciones que antes mencioné en la fila y asiento digitados y me  muestra un "V","L" o "R" en la tabla. Ya escribí un código que hace lo que se pide, el problema es que al volver a colocar una fila, un puesto y una opción (comprar, reservar o liberar) lo hace de nuevo y no guarda los valores anteriores. Aqui el código:

Codigo del formulario principal

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTML/estiloIndex.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="encabezado">
            <h3>Gesti&oacute;n de reserva de asientos</h3>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_POST['fila']) && !isset($_POST['puesto']) && !isset($_POST['option'])) {
            mostrarTeatro(asignarValor());
        } else {

            mostrarTeatro(asignarValor($_POST['fila'], $_POST['puesto'], $_POST['option']));
        }

        ?>

        <div id="formulario">
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <table >
                    <tr><td>Fila:</td><td><input type="text" name="fila"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Puesto:</td><td><input type="text" name="puesto"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reservar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="R"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Comprar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="V"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Liberar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="L"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="borrar"></td></tr>

                </table>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Codigo de la función que muestra la tabla HTML de los asientos:

```
function mostrarTeatro($arr) {
    //require_once 'Arrays/ManejoArray.php';

    $index = 0;
    ?>
    <div id="divAsientos">
        <table id="teatro">
            <tr><td colspan="6">Escenario</td></tr>
            <tr><td> </td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++) {
                        if ($j == 0) {
                            ?>
                            <td><?php echo ($index += 1) ?></td>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <td><?php echo $arr[$i][$j - 1]; ?></td>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Código de la función que recibe los valores POST del formulario y modifica y retorna el arreglo:

```
function asignarValor($indice1 = null, $indice2 = null, $operacion = null) {

    $arrayTeatro = [
        ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"],
        ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"],
        ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"],
        ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"],
        ["L", "L", "L", "L", "L"]
    ];


    if ($indice1 == null && $indice2 == null && $operacion == null) {
        return $arrayTeatro;
    } else {
        switch ($operacion) {
            case "L":

                if ($arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] == "L") {
                    echo "<p>Este asiento esta libre</p>";
                } else if ($arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] == "V") {
                    echo "<p>No se puede cambiar el estado de un asiento vendido</p>";
                } else {

                    $arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] = $operacion;
                }

                break;
            case "R":
                if ($arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] == "R") {
                    echo "<p>Ya esta reservado este asiento</p>";
                } else if ($arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] == "V") {
                    echo "<p>No se puede cambiar el estado de un asiento vendido</p>";
                } else {
                    $arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] = $operacion;
                }

                break;
            case "V":
                if ($arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] == "V") {
                    echo "<p>Ya esta vendido este asiento</p>";
                } else {
                    $arrayTeatro[$indice1 - 1][$indice2 - 1] = $operacion;
                }
                break;
        }

        return $arrayTeatro;
    }
}
```

Les agradecería que me ayudaran a encontrar la forma de hacer que los valores no se reinicien al momento de colocar otra fila y puesto, he encontrado que tal vez se puede convertir el arreglo en una cadena de caracteres y colocarlo en un textarea pero no se como se debe alimentar la tabla con esos valores. Saludos.
Resultado visual del programa para mayor referencia: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AksM3d9DORvruD71Ber6wKNzT8Vv

Comment: podrias incluir un ejemplo visual del resultado deseado? ya que no logro entenderte del todo!

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AksM3d9DORvruD71Ber6wKNzT8Vv en este enlace puedes ver la interfaz, es sencilla solo debe mostrar en la tabla la operación (Reserva, compra, liberar puesto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo utilizando variables de [SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) ejemplo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            tr>td{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="encabezado">
            <h3>Gesti&oacute;n de reserva de asientos</h3>
        </div>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>reservas</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php

                session_start();

                    function asignarValor($fila=null,$puesto=null,$status=null){
                    $size = 5; // define le tama;o de la matriz

                    // arreglo para imitar la base de datos
                    if (empty($_SESSION["puestos"])) {
                        $_SESSION["puestos"]=[];
                    }

                    // validamos que se envien datos para procesar
                    if($fila !=null && $puesto !=null){

                        $key="$fila-$puesto";

                        if(array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION["puestos"]) && $_SESSION["puestos"][$key]=="V" ){
                            echo "ya esta Vendido este puesto!";
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION["puestos"][$key]=$status;
                        }
                    }


                    for($i=1; $i <= $size; $i++){
                        echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>"; // imprime la primera columna con numeros

                            for($j=1; $j <= $size; $j++) {

                                $tmp="$i-$j"; // creamos la llave con las posiciones

                                if(array_key_exists($tmp,$_SESSION["puestos"])){ // verificamos que exista
                                    $color = strtoupper($_SESSION["puestos"][$tmp]) == "V" ? "red" : "yellow";
                                    // cambiamos a mayusucala y validamos que sea V para ponerlo rojo o de lo contrario que sea R ponerlo amarillo
                                    echo"<td style='background-color:".$color.";'>".strtoupper($_SESSION["puestos"][$tmp])."</td>"; // agregamos el stado 
                                }else{
                                    echo"<td style='background-color:green;'>L</td>"; // si no existe ponemos la L y pintamos de verde
                                }   
                            }
                        echo "</tr>"; // cerramos el tr
                    }
                }


                // inicializamos las variables
                $C=0; // continuar
                $fila = null;
                $puesto = null;
                $status = null;

                if(!empty($_POST["fila"])) {
                    $fila = $_POST["fila"];
                    $C++;
                }

                if(!empty($_POST["puesto"])) {
                    $puesto = $_POST["puesto"];
                    $C++;
                }

                if(!empty($_POST["option"])) {
                    $status = $_POST["option"];
                    $C++;
                }

                // se envian todos los datos
                if($C == 3){
                    asignarValor($fila,$puesto,$status);
                }else{
                    // si no se envio un dato
                    asignarValor();
                }

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="formulario">
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <table >
                    <tr><td>Fila:</td><td><input type="text" name="fila"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Puesto:</td><td><input type="text" name="puesto"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Reservar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="R"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Comprar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="V"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Liberar:</td><td><input type="radio" name="option" value="L"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"></td><td><input type="reset" value="Borrar" name="borrar"></td></tr>

                </table>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bryro eres un genio. Te hago una última pregunta: estas sentencias $key="$fila-$puesto"; y $tmp="$i-$j" no  las comprendo del todo, podrias explicarme su uso?

Comment: es solo para crear las llaves ejemplo 4-2, 3-1, 5-4 etc... solo crea el string que es el nombre de la llave!